# hover button width not functioning as intended

Tags: html, css

the website I am designing has an interactive roll over button but when hovered over the width of the button increases extremely but I would still like to keep the functionality of the button I have removed and changed the width in the stylesheet but hasn't change the outcome.

Kindest regards, Validix.

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(10, 10, 10);
}

html,
body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Announcment bar */
.alert {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #2a7a85;
    color: white;
}

.closebtn {
    margin-left: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
    color: black;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}
/* Navigation bar */
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
}

ul.topnav li {
    float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 25px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: rgb(55, 81, 165);
}

ul.topnav li a.active {
    background-color: #0cc0d8;
}

ul.topnav li.right {
    float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    ul.topnav li.right,
    ul.topnav li {
        float: none;
    }
}

/* Services Section on product page */
.services {
    background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.services h1 {
    background-color: #77ff7e;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to right,
        #00eeff 0%,
        #0df1de 0%,
        #0ad3f7 21%,
        #2b86db 52%,
        #23a6da 78%,
        #06afda 100%
    );
    background-size: 100%;

    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.services__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.services__card {
    margin: 1rem;
    height: 525px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
            to bottom,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
            rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6) 100%
        ),
        url('img/bus.PNG');
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
}

.services__card:before {
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.services__card:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(
            to bottom,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
            rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9) 100%
        ),
        url('img/bus.PNG');
}

.services__card h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 30px;
}

.services__card p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 30px;
}

.services__card button {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #19b6bb;
    position: absolute;
    top: 440px;
    left: 30px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.services__card button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.services__card:hover {
    transform: scale(1.075);
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .services {
        height: 1600px;
    }

    .services h1 {
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin-top: 12rem;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .services {
        height: 1400px;
    }

    .services h1 {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }

    .services__card {
        width: 300px;
    }
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .text {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
}

/* "not needed*/

.textcontainer2 {
    font-size: 2.5vh;
    color: whitesmoke;

    /* buttons */
}
.main__btn {
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #008cff 0%, #0e0bec 100%);
    padding: 14px 32px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    outline: none;
}

.main__btn a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main__btn:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #4837ff;
    transition: all 0.35s;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.main__btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.main__btn:hover:after {
    width: 100%;


}

h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    color: blue;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.btn-centering {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.text {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="icon" href="img/icon.png" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="alert">
                <span
                    class="closebtn"
                    onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';"
                    >&times;</span
                >
                <center>
                    <strong>DEALS NOW ON!</strong> Upto 30% discounts this
                    christmas
                </center>
            </div>

            <ul class="topnav">
                <li><img src="img/logo.png" /></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Products.html">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li class="right"><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="btn-centering">
                <div class="text"><h1>Kipplo.co.uk</h1></div>
                <button class="main__btn">
                    <a href="#">More Information</a>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to keep the functionality, but at the same time make it easier to hover off? I am struggling to understand your description of the problem :)

Comment: Hello Stanley, I would like the button to still have the hover functionality, but when a end-user hovers over the button it is significantly larger than intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//hello You forgot to make the position of the button (main__btn)relative

```
    body {
        background-color: rgb(10, 10, 10);
    }

    html,
    body {
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    /* Announcment bar */
    .alert {
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #2a7a85;
        color: white;
    }

    .closebtn {
        margin-left: 15px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .closebtn:hover {
        color: black;
    }

    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    /* Navigation bar */
    ul.topnav {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
    }

    ul.topnav li {
        float: left;
    }

    ul.topnav li a {
        display: block;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 25px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: rgb(55, 81, 165);
    }

    ul.topnav li a.active {
        background-color: #0cc0d8;
    }

    ul.topnav li.right {
        float: right;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        ul.topnav li.right,
        ul.topnav li {
            float: none;
        }
    }

    /* Services Section on product page */
    .services {
        background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .services h1 {
        background-color: #77ff7e;
        background-image: linear-gradient(
            to right,
            #00eeff 0%,
            #0df1de 0%,
            #0ad3f7 21%,
            #2b86db 52%,
            #23a6da 78%,
            #06afda 100%
        );
        background-size: 100%;

        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
        margin-bottom: 5rem;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }

    .services__container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .services__card {
        margin: 1rem;
        height: 525px;
        width: 400px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(
                to bottom,
                rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
                rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.6) 100%
            ),
            url('img/bus.PNG');
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .services__card:before {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }

    .services__card:nth-child(2) {
        background-image: linear-gradient(
                to bottom,
                rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%,
                rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9) 100%
            ),
            url('img/bus.PNG');
    }

    .services__card h2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 350px;
        left: 30px;
    }

    .services__card p {
        position: absolute;
        top: 400px;
        left: 30px;
    }

    .services__card button {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        background: #19b6bb;
        position: absolute;
        top: 440px;
        left: 30px;
        font-size: 1rem;
    }

    .services__card button:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .services__card:hover {
        transform: scale(1.075);
        transition: 0.2s ease-in;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
        .services {
            height: 1600px;
        }

        .services h1 {
            font-size: 2rem;
            margin-top: 12rem;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .services {
            height: 1400px;
        }

        .services h1 {
            font-size: 1.2rem;
        }

        .services__card {
            width: 300px;
        }
    }

    /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
        .text {
            font-size: 11px;
        }
    }

    /* "not needed*/

    .textcontainer2 {
        font-size: 2.5vh;
        color: whitesmoke;

        /* buttons */
    }
    .main__btn {
 

//here look
 position: relative;
        font-size: 1rem;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #008cff 0%, #0e0bec 100%);
        padding: 14px 32px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: all 0.35s;
        outline: none;
    }

    .main__btn a {
   
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .main__btn:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 100%;
        background: #4837ff;
        transition: all 0.35s;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }

    .main__btn:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .main__btn:hover:after {
        width: 100%;


    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 60px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
        color: blue;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    .btn-centering {
        flex-grow: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .text {
        width: 100%;
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <link rel="icon" href="img/icon.png" />

            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="alert">
                    <span
                        class="closebtn"
                        onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';"
                        >&times;</span
                    >
                    <center>
                        <strong>DEALS NOW ON!</strong> Upto 30% discounts this
                        christmas
                    </center>
                </div>

                <ul class="topnav">
                    <li><img src="img/logo.png" /></li>
                    <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Products.html">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class="right"><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>

                <div class="btn-centering">
                    <div class="text"><h1>Kipplo.co.uk</h1></div>
                    <button class="main__btn">
                        <a href="#">More Information</a>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much buddy, it works perfectly! You're a valuable member of the community!!